# XML to CSV with value change

Tags: php, xml, csv

I want to convert XML to CSV file with replacing some values.
To simple convert i used this script:

```
$xml_file_input='file.xml';
$csv_file_output = 'file.csv';
function convertXmlToCsvFile($xml_file_input, $csv_file_output) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($xml_file_input);
    $output_file = fopen($csv_file_output, 'w');
    $header = false;
    foreach($xml as $key => $value){
        if(!$header) {
            fputcsv($output_file, array_keys(get_object_vars($value)));
            $header = true;
        }
        fputcsv($output_file, get_object_vars($value));
    }
    fclose($output_file);
}
convertXmlToCsvFile($xml_file_input,$csv_file_output);
```

For example
value in XML

> "New red carpet 130x200"

In CSV i want to have

> "New carpet 130x200"

XML content:

```
<offers xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1">
<script/>
<offer>
<title>New red carpet 130x200</title>
<price>123</price>
</offer>
<offer>
<title>New green carpet 170x300</title>
<price>234</price>
</offer>
</offers>
```

I will be grateful for any help!

Comment: Assuming that the conversion to csv is not the problem, can you edit your question with a representative sample of the xml?

Comment: Edited. i was added xml content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the specific problem of modifying the text content of the target element, try something like:

```
$targets = $xml->xpath('//offer/title[text()="New red carpet 130x200"]');
foreach ($targets as $target) 
    $target[0] = "Another Carpet";
echo $xml->asXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
<offers xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1">    
<script/>    
<offer>    
<title>Another Carpet</title>    
<price>123</price>    
</offer>    
<offer>    
<title>New green carpet 170x300</title>    
<price>234</price>    
</offer>    
</offers>
```